How do I change the output language in a Jupyter notebook?
I'm writing the notebook in spanish and I need the LaTeX-generated content to also be in spanish. For example, instead of References I need Referencias and instead of the date November 1, 2024 I need 1 de noviembre de 2024.
A workaround is to generate a LaTeX output, add \usepackage[spanish]{babel} in the preamble and then compile it manually to a PDF.
But my question is: is there a way to put this directly into the notebook (ipynb file)?
I've searched for solutions like passing options to packages in jupyter, extending the preamble in the metadata of the notebook, but these options don't seem to exist.
Note: I'm using Jupyter Lab.
